# Getting checkbox checked items content in a string array in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox containing checkboxes. I want to get all the checkbox checked items content in a string array. How can I get this?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"> 
    <ListBox x:Name="TrackingView1" Margin="9,0,2,5"> 
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <CheckBox x:Name="fileNameLinkButton" Content="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" /> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListBox> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please provide your code (XAML) and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal ` <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="TrackingView1" Margin="9,0,2,5">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="fileNameLinkButton"
                                     Content="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"
                                     FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal The ListBox ItemSource is bound to a string array containing file names from isolated storage.

Comment: What are you binding your ListBox to? it should be bound to an ObservableCollection of elements containing a bool representing the state of the CheckBox.
If you have this scenario you can just query the list for the element that have Checked true.

Comment: @MBen My ListBox is bound to a string[] containing the name of files in the isolated storage.

Comment: I would create a class that has FileName (string) and IsChecked (bool). Then put that in an ObservableCollection. Your checkBox will be bound to the bool in that Class. Would be easier to find which one was selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VisualTreeHelper to retrieve the datatemplate items,
use this method to get the first item of datatemplate

```
 //method for finding first element of the listbox data template
    private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            { return (T)child; }
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

then use this code in the event you want to, for example on a button click

```
 int itemsCount = this.TrackingView1.Items.Count;
 List<string> myList = new  List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
 {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)this.TrackingView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            CheckBox tagregCheckBox = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<CheckBox>(item);
            if((bool)tagregCheckBox.IsChecked)                
              myList.Add(tagregCheckBox.Content.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Everything is working fine but when i debug "Reference is not a valid visual DependencyObject" exception at the line "var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);" I works for first some checkbox item but after sometime I get this exception and my app closes. When the exception is encountered, parentElement is equal to null. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It seems for more items this error shows up. I haven't found the solution yet but will post here as soon as I find. If you also know how to solve it please write here as well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a classic TextBook approach, You could bind "TrackingView1" to a IList, where PersonClass looks some thing like

```
public class PersonClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public PersonClass(string name, bool isSelected)
    {
    this.Name = name;
    this.IsSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

and at the point where you want to collect your data,

```
string[] checkedNames = (from name in Names
            where name.IsSelected
            select name.Name).ToArray();
```

I would actually avoid the ToArray(), and accessing the UI directly